# Get the other column on the same row

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my MySQL Table:

DB name: `dbname` Table name: `tbname`

```
column1    |   column2
Info 1     |   Other 1
Info 2     |   Other 2
```

What I'm trying to get is: In PHP I have the value `Info 1` as `$info`, I want to search in the DB to get `Other 1` on the same row, and add it to variable `$other`.

How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to create connection like

```
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$database);
```

Then do

```
$selectquery="SELECT column2 FROM tbname WHERE column1 = '$info'";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$selectquery) or die(mysqli_error());
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Comment: I changed the last `$result` to `$query` because is seems to be correct. I'm getting the following error: `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /directory/myfile.php on line xx` Any ideas? (BTW, the line is the last line starting with `$result`)

Comment: Show us your code and also `$con` is your connection variable.

Comment: That's the line with error `$result= mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: See the edit, I think you have created connection using mysql_* . You need to use mysqli_*

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Are you sure that the last line is correct? You put the same, undefined variable.

Comment: Sorry my bad, in last line you have to pass `$query`

Comment: I did this `$result=mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die(mysqli_error());` and it gave me the error in comment #1. If I don't add `or die(mysqli_error())` there is just a white screen.